# Rails Feature tests fails after bundle update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, poltergeist

After bundle update my tests with `js: true` fails because Capybara or Poltergeist returns absolute path for links instead of relative.

Example:

```
expect(edit_link[:href]).to eq(edit_agreement_path agreement)
```

Fail message:

```
expected: "/agreements/1/edit"
got: "http://127.0.0.1:55714/agreements/1/edit"
```

In the failed snapshot i can see that my links are still relative as expected.

Any ideas what is changed and how to fix this? Don`t really like idea to go through all my tests to fix this issue.

For standard not js tests all work as expected - got relative path for links.

Sorry for my English.

Comment: "Any ideas what is changed" - gem changed. I would look at the diff between the two versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poltergeist was updated to behave the same as selenium (prefer element property over attribute in most cases).  You'll need to either revert or update your tests.  A better solution is to actually specify the href when finding the link in the first place

```
expect(page).to have_link('edit', href: edit_agreement_path(agreement))
```

Or

```
edit_link = page.find(:link, 'edit', href: edit_agreement_path(agreement))
```

if you care about the value of href, although the actual value of href really isn't something for integration tests to worry about.  They should be more about, if I click it do I end up on a page with the ability to edit the item

Comment: Thanks, already fixed my tests.Checking for value cause we have complicated index view generator and few students in our team - i want to be sure that all index pages have all necessary links with correct values.